# What Am I doing Wrong In Regressing and Graphing Exponential Plot?

Tags: r, data-visualization, curve-fitting, lm

So I am new to R and have just been learning it for a month, and have encountered this frustrating problem.  I have some basic data and am attempting to fit an exponential curve to it and then afterwards graph it.  This is my code so far:

```
y <- c(1594,343,57,20,9)
time <- 1:5
fit <- lm(log(y) ~ log(time))

plot(time,y)
abline(fit)
```

After doing all this, I simply get this weird line on the bottom of my graph.

[image: Plot not as expected?]

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: This question is only seemingly about R. It is actually a mistake in the model, ,as @Hiromi 's answer shows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your linear model is fitted on $log(y)$ and $log(time)$, so when you call `abline(fit)`, it produces the fitted line for that model. You could do this instead:

```
y <- c(1594,343,57,20,9)
time <- 1:5
fit <- lm(log(y) ~ log(time))
plot(log(time),log(y), pch=16)
abline(fit)
```

[image: Plot of fitted model]

But if you would like to visualise on your original scale, you would need to exponentiate your $y$ to revert back the scale. Actually, I'm not sure why you need to log your time variable, it will make it difficult to interpret your coefficient. Rather, I would do it this way:

```
fit2 <- lm(log(y) ~ time)
fitted_y2=exp(fit2$fitted.values)
plot(time,y,ylim=c(0,max(fitted_y2,y)), pch=16)
lines(time,fitted_y2)
```

[image: Plot of model log(y)~time revert back to original scale]